# heroku node.js scheduler is not working

Tags: node.js, heroku, scheduler

I am trying to schedule a task after 10 minutes in node.js heroku. I have created a file worker.js in program main directory. In worker.js I have just called the controller function that I want to schedule like this :

```
const reports = require('./app/controllers/reports');
reports.sendEmail();
```

sendEmail function use to send emails. in Heroku scheduler I have add worker.js as :

[image]

but my scheduler is not working. What I am missing in my configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Edit your Heroku Scheduler dashboard, and type `node worker.js` for the command to be executed.

Comment: if route this function through browser it works perfectly but if try to schedule it it does not show any response

Comment: Post your Heroku log so we can see what's happening.

Comment: on some posts at stack overflow they were using only worker.js but it is not working through it

Comment: 2018-03-26T11:12:00.620709+00:00 app[api]: Starting process with command `node worker.js` by user scheduler@addons.heroku.com
2018-03-26T11:12:07.937223+00:00 heroku[scheduler.3066]: Starting process with command `node worker.js`
2018-03-26T11:12:09.362869+00:00 heroku[scheduler.3066]: State changed from starting to up
2018-03-26T11:12:10.995333+00:00 heroku[scheduler.3066]: Process exited with status 0
2018-03-26T11:12:11.029493+00:00 heroku[scheduler.3066]: State changed from up to complete

Comment: Does your worker.js emit any logs? If not, make it do so, so we can see if it is getting run by the scheduler. Also, is worker.js in the same directory as your Procfile?

Comment: console.log('Enter in worker js file');
  i have add console.log and it is printing in log file when scheduler invoke

Comment: So your original problem is solved. Your scheduler is now configured correctly, based on the answer I posted. You now have a different problem, which is obviously something to do with your code in worker.js. I would suggest you post a separate question about that, if necessary. You can use "heroku run node worker.js" to run your worker.js file in a Heroku one-off dyno "on demand", without having to wait for the scheduler. That should make it easier for you to debug your code.